# How do you map the <u> key to something else in vim?

Tags: vim

I tried `:map <u> :help<CR>` but it doesn't work. The u key keeps undoing instead of going to help.

How do you map  to something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

does this work for you?

```
nnoremap u :help<cr>
```

Your mapping works too, actually, you didn't map the key <kbd>u</kbd> to `help`, you mapped <kbd><</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>></kbd> to `help`.

another question, do you really want to have that mapping (by overwriting <kbd>u</kbd>)?

Comment: Real programmers never use their editor's "undo" feature. ;-)

Comment: @romainl vim has later cmd, real programmer could `:later 30d`, then do release ;-)

Comment: lol, I'm not really mapping u to :help. What I'd like to do is something that I think would be more convenient than using hjkl for movement: using hujk for movement, where u is up and j is down, like arrow keys, and making l the undo key.

Comment: Alright, so I tried ":map u k", ":map k l", and ":map l u" but then I get "recursive mapping" errors. How can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: @trusktr if you look my answer, I used `nnoremap`, it means `normal norecursive map`

Comment: @Kent Sweet, it worked. Thanks for the explanation. That would've been nice to include in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're got it almost right; the `<...>` notation is only used for special keys and modifier key combinations, see `:help key-notation`.